# Quickest way to get a Map<Name, Id> from SOQL ? i.e. Required field to go before object id

Tags: soql, map

Need this map to populate the lookup field on a child object, finding id of lookup object by it's Name.
e.g. `[SELECT Name, Id FROM Account] --> Map<Name, Id>`

Comment: Don't think there is a quickest way, you need to iterate over a for loop to prepare the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "quick way" to do so; it always requires a loop:

```
Map<String, Id> name2Id = new Map<String, Id>();
for(Sobject record: records) {
  name2Id.put(record.Name, record.Id);
}
```

Replace `SObject` with the correct data type.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing so far (plus query), just thought 
as this seem to be quite a useful and imho: popular requirement, thought there'd be a clever workaround to avoid these 3 lines. Must be just getting lazy..

Answer (score 6):

Code a loop.

But in general, you will need to build a `Map<String, Set<Id>>` unless you have duplicate rules that disallow duplicate Account names:

```
Map<String, Set<Id>> m = new Map<String, Set<Id>>();
for (Account a : [
        select Name, Id 
        from Account
        where ...
        ]) {
    Set<Id> s = m.get(a.Name);
    if (s == null) {
        s = new Set<Id>();
        m.put(a.Name, s);
    }
    s.add(a.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase Bill Clinton, it depends on the definition of `quickest`

For me, quickest means quickest to code as unless you have some CPU-sensitive transaction, your time is more valuable than SFDC server time. And this pattern occurs over and over again in your org.

To that end, I built a small library of pivot methods that allow you to do this in one line

```
Map<String,Account[]> accountsById = 
  Util.pivotSobjectsByString(Account.Name,[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
```

where the pivot method is defined as:

```
public static map<String,List<SObject>> pivotSObjectsByString(Schema.SObjectField fldToken, SObject[] sobjList) {
    map<String,List<SObject>>   res = new map<String,List<SObject>> ();
    for (Sobject sobj: sobjList == null ? new list<Sobject>() : sobjlist) {
        String pivotKey = (String) sobj.get(fldToken);
        if (res.containsKey(pivotKey)) {
            res.get(pivotKey).add(sobj);
        }
        else {
            Sobject[] typedSobjs = makeTypedSobjList(sobj); // do this so resulting list.getSobjectType() doesn't return null
            typedSobjs.add(sobj);
            res.put(pivotKey,typedSobjs);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static Sobject[] makeTypedSobjList(Sobject sobj) {
    return (Sobject[]) Type.forName('List<'+sobj.getSObjectType()+'>').newInstance();
}
```

The nice thing about this method (and there are equivalent ones for Decimal, Date, ...) is that you always get back a list of matching sObjects, hence addressing duplicates (or which might be empty) so your calling code merely needs to iterate over lists and *never test for null*

If you want a more powerful library that allows pivoting on parent fields as well, check out @Aidan [library SobjectIndex](https://bitbucket.org/aidan_harding/sobjectindex/src/master/)

Comment: Seems like it would be better to name the class `Pivot` and the method `byString`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - as usual, you're probably right but I copy-pasted this from my org where I've developed a large library of useful methods into one container. Add this to the pile of good refactoring ideas

Comment: Ah, the terrifying monolith. Personally, I would never use anything in a class called `Util` for fear of being tethered to it.