# Compare map value and set<string> and retain string that doesn't exist in set

Tags: apex, map

I'm iterating over below map. I want to compare map values and set and iterate over the map.values that doesn't exist in set

```
Set<String> articleIds = new Set<String>(); 

List<object__c> cuList = [SELECT Article_ID__c FROM object__c WHERE Article_ID__c IN: cuWrapperMap.keySet()];

            if((cuWrapperMap.keySet().size() > cuList.size()) && cuList.size() > 0){
                for(object__c cua : caList){
                    articleIds.add(cua.Article_ID__c);
                    for(articleWrapper wrpr : cuWrapperMap.values()){
                        //Here I want to iterate only for wrpr.articleId's that doesn't exist in the set.
                        if(!(wrpr.articleId).contains(articleIds)){

                            object__c cuaRec = new object__c();
                            cuaRec.Case__c = wrpr.caseId;
                            cuaRec.Article_ID__c = (wrpr.articleId).substring(0, 15);
                            createCUAList.add(cuaRec);
                        }
                    }    
                }

            }
insert createCUAList;
```

Comment: What part of your code doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: at the surface, this looks simpler to do by selecting into a Map and then pivoting the map based on `article_id__c`.  see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/275079/2602)

Comment: Hey Nick, if(!(wrpr.articleId).contains(articleIds)){ this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use [`String`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class's `contains` method whereas you should be using [`Set`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) class's `contains` method. And string's contains method does not take set as parameter, hence you might be receiving the compilation error.

**String's contains method**

> **contains(substring)**
>
> Returns true if and only if the String that called the method contains
>   the specified sequence of characters in substring.

```
String myString1 = 'abcde';
String myString2 = 'abcd';
Boolean result = myString1.contains(myString2);
System.assertEquals(result, true);
```

**Set's contains method**

> **contains(setElement)**
>
> Returns true if the set contains the specified element.

```
Set<String> myString = new Set<String>{'a', 'b'};
Boolean result = myString.contains('z');
System.assertEquals(false, result);
```

So change your below code

```
if(!(wrpr.articleId).contains(articleIds))
```

to

```
if(!articleIds.contains(wrpr.articleId))
```

which will check if the `wrpr.articleId` is present in `articleIds` set or not

Comment: Hi Vijay, if(!articleIds.contains(wrpr.articleId)) works for my logic to insert records. It's not working for my logic to delete records. I've update above code with my deleteArticles method. Can you pls check?

Comment: @RaviTeja your debug doesn't prove that whether the `contains` methods is working or not. Debug `articleIds` and `wrpr.articleId` to verify that.