# How to iterate over Map with same key, but different values?

Tags: apex, map, for

I have this map:

```
for(Opportunity opp: [Select Id, AccountId From Opportunity Where Id IN :SetIds]){
      mapAcctOpp.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Id);
}
```

When I try to iterate over this map like this:

```
Map<Id, String> toSave = new Map<Id, String>();

for(Account tempAct: [Select Id, Field__c from Account Where Id IN : mapAcctOpp.keySet()]){
    toSave.put(mapAcctOpp.get(tempAct.Id), Field__c);
}
```

My `toSave` map is unable to capture all the `OppIds` when I have same Account. I am not sure how to loop over the keys and values and have it work for both scenarios: Unique Account Ids and different Account Ids.

Comment: You cannot have *same key* added in a Map with different values. Keys are always unique, the time you add another key with same value, the older gets overridden. Are you saying your *key* can contain multiple values, in this case multiple Opportunity Ids, and that's what you want to retrieve?

Comment: You might use map of list by id structure: ```Map<Id, List<Id>> opp_ids_by_account_id;```. In that case you can write ```for(Id opp_id : opp_ids_by_account_id.get(some_account_id)) { /*code*/}```

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/275079/2602 for a way to do this pattern over and over again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the approaches could be to use `Map<Id, Set<Id>>` structure in order to collect all data.

Consider following example:

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> opportunity_ids_by_account_ids = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
for(Opportunity opp: [Select Id, AccountId From Opportunity Where Id IN :SetIds]){
      if (!opportunity_ids_by_account_ids.containsKey(opp.AccountId)) {
          opportunity_ids_by_account_ids.put(opp.AccountId, new Set<Id>());
      }
      opportunity_ids_by_account_ids.get(opp.AccountId).add(opp.Id);
}
```

In that case, per each account id, there would be set of opportunity ids, so that can be utilized in following way:

```
Map<Id, String> toSave = new Map<Id, String>();

for(Account acc: [Select Id, Field__c from Account Where Id IN : mapAcctOpp.keySet()]){
    if(opportunity_ids_by_account_ids.containsKey(acc.Id)){
        for(Id opp_id : opportunity_ids_by_account_ids.get(acc.Id)) {
             toSave.put(opp_id, acc.Field__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I need to learn these data structures. Can you please post a resource where I can learn more about these? Like where can I learn when/how to use, `Map<Id, Set<Id>>()` and others for specific use-cases?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a map of opportunity id as a key and set of opportunity ids i.e : `Map<Id, Set<Id>>`
2. Use that map keys(accountids) in SOQL
3. Create a map which is store field values with opportunityid i.e `Map<Id,String>` for your third soql